# drive/driven gears

Tags: gears

Is it possible to have a drive and driven gear on the same shaft?  Rookie question, I know.  I've been doing a lot of googling and sometimes I think I understand that they can, but reading the definitions, I don't understand how that's possible.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if one gear is keyed to the shaft and the other on a bearing or sleeve - has been used in aftermarket overdrive units by Fairey for example.

Edit : also old belt-driven equipment had fixed / sliding pulleys which could be locked together or unlocked to provide a "neutral" as most were driven from a common shaft in machine shops.

Comment: Thank you.  If I wanted to learn more about a drive and driven gear sharing a shaft, can you recommend any sites?

Comment: I did not search for the two examples .... But you could search for flat belt drive or flat belt saws etc.

Comment: try here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rohloff_Speedhub